# Train SVM for car plate recognition in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, svm, knn

I'm trying to create a car plate recognition system, using OpenCV (C++). I've already seen [this example](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition) on GitHub, but I want to use SVM, instead of K-nearest neighbours or Arificial Neural Networks.

I trained a SVM only for two classes (positive or negative), so how can I train to classify characters on the car plate?

I have 22 symbols (Y is the last one symbol) (i.e. 22 classes), should I create a bunch of binary SVMs? For example SVM(0,1), SVM(0,2)....SVM(Y,0), SVM(Y,1)...

If this is the case how can I merge all this files into one, to use it in recognition?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Multiclass_SVM

Comment: Am i understanding correctly, that the scheme "one-versus-all" is the same, that i described above?

Comment: Your explanation wasn't very clear, but I guess it could be.   I'm not sure why you're insisting on using SVM, when a template matching OCR would probably do a better job.

Comment: Well, i saw an article, where accuracy of SVM recognition reached almost 97%, and it's also easier for me, i never used template matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiclass solution has one SVM per class, not two. So you have `SVM(A)` to `SVM(Y)`. `SVM(A)` tries to separate A from B-Y, `SVM(Y)` tries to separate Y from A-X.

A hierarchy can be a better solution. If the V and Y are similar, you can have an `SVM(VY)` first, and then a V-versus-Y SVM.

I don't see the problem (or the reason) for merging files.

Comment: Thanks for clearing thigs up! But how can i train this multiclass svm? I trained only binary SVM, is it the same approach? For example: folder with character A - is positive variants, and folder with character B - is negative, and so on A-C, A-D, but with this method i get a lot of SVMs. I can't understand how to create one SVM per class (for example for class A)

Comment: @pavel_s: As I said: Character A is positive, **all other** characters **together** are negative.